# Dihedral group of order 2n

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, dihedral-groups

I would appreciate if someone could prove this for me:

Let G be a dihedral group of order 2n and suppose H is a cyclic quotient group of G. Show that |H|is less than or equal 2.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) What are the only *cyclic dihedral* groups ?

2) Show that a quotient group of a dihedral group is again a dihedral group.

Comment: these are groups of order two?

Comment: @cf12418 I don't understand your question.